# Self-containing array deep equals

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I need to perform structural comparison on two Object[] arrays which may contain themselves:

```
Object[] o1 = new Object[] { "A", null };
o1[1] = o1;

Object[] o2 = new Object[] { "A", null };
o2[1] = o2;

Arrays.deepEquals(o1, o2); // undefined behavior
```

Unfortunately, the `deepEquals` doesn't work in this case. The example above should yield true.

**Is there an algorithm which can reliably calculate this?**

My idea is roughly as follows:

```
List<Object> xs = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object> ys = new ArrayList<>();

boolean equal(Object[] o1, Object[] o2, List<Object> xs, List<Object> ys) {
   xs.add(o1);
   ys.add(o2);
   boolean result = true;
   for (int i = 0; i < o1.length; i++) {
       if (o1[i] instanceof Object[]) {
           int idx1 = xs.lastIndexOf(o1[i]);
           if (idx1 >= 0) { idx1 = xs.size() - idx1 - 1; }
           if (o2[i] instanceof Object[]) {
               int idx2 = xs.lastIndexOf(o2[i]);
               if (idx2 >= 0) { idx2 = ys.size() - idx2 - 1; }
               if (idx1 == idx2) {
                   if (idx1 >= 0) {
                       continue;
                   }
                   if (!equal(o1[i], o2[i], xs, ys)) {
                       result = false;
                       break;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   xs.removeLast();
   ys.removeLast();
   return result;
}
```

Comment: That's a heck of a question.  Do you have a practical reason for implementing a paradox?

Comment: This is the simplified version of the original problem. I need to tell the relation (equal, inequal, A extends B) between two XSD-s based on structural comparison. In XSD, you can define recursive structures such as trees. I need the ability to compare them as well.

Comment: Your example code has some compile-errors, but once they're addressed, it has the logic-error that the method can never return `false`, since the only way that it could return `false` is if a recursive call had previously returned `false`. So your method always either returns `true`, or does not return. This is understandable: if you had working code, you wouldn't be asking your question. But as a result, it's really not clear, at least to me, what you want your function to do. What do you mean by "structural comparison"? Can you explain what the method's return-value should mean, exactly?

Comment: @ruakh I omitted the non-array comparison from my example. That may result in false.

Comment: @ruakh The result should mean, that if the two arrays were flattened out up to infinity, each pair of elements would equal. I.e., both o1 and o2 would look like AAAAAAA... The structural comparison comes into place when I need to compare XSD of different systems at the two ends of a delivery channel, whether an entity in their own IT system can be matched to an entity in the other.

Comment: @kd304: So is it correct to say that: two arrays are structurally equal if they have the same length, and for each index, either both contain `null`, or both contain non-array objects that are equal (according to `equals()`), or both contain arrays that are structurally equal?

Comment: @ruakh yes, ad infinitum. But need to check it without infinite recursion.

Comment: (Ah, sorry, I just realized that I should have Googled. Somehow it didn't sound like a standard term to me, but I find that is defined online, e.g. at http://lucatarrini.net/?p=845. Sorry about that!)

Comment: Googling around I came across the IStructureComparator interface in Eclipse (http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/compare/structuremergeviewer/IStructureComparator.html). Can't tell if it's worth taking a look into it. Seems pretty complicated at a first glance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments above, your code has some compile errors, and you've left out a lot of it, which makes it hard to be 100% sure of *exactly* how it's supposed to work once the code is completed. But after finishing the code, fixing one clear typo (you wrote `idx2 = xs.lastIndexOf(o2[i])`, but I'm sure you meant `idx2 = ys.lastIndexOf(o2[i])`) and one thing that I *think* is a typo (I don't *think* that you meant for `if (!equal(o1[i], o2[i], xs, ys))` to be nested inside `if (idx1 == idx2)`), removing some no-op code, and restructuring a bit (to a style that I find clearer; YMMV), I get this:

```
boolean equal(final Object[] o1, final Object[] o2)
{
    return _equal(o1, o2, new ArrayList<Object>(), new ArrayList<Object>());
}

private static boolean _equal(final Object[] o1, final Object[] o2,
                                 final List<Object> xs, final List<Object> ys)
{
    if(o1.length != o2.length)
        return false;

    xs.add(o1);
    ys.add(o2);
    try
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < o1.length; i++)
        {
            if(o1[i] == null && o2[i] == null)
                continue;
            if(o1[i] == null || o2[i] == null)
                return false;
            if(o1[i].equals(o2[i]))
                continue;
            if(! (o1[i] instanceof Object[]) || ! (o2[i] instanceof Object[]))
                return false;

            final int idx1 = xs.lastIndexOf(o1[i]);

            if(idx1 >= 0 && idx1 == ys.lastIndexOf(o2[i]))
                continue;

            if(! _equal((Object[])o1[i], (Object[])o2[i], xs, ys))
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
    finally
    {
        xs.remove(xs.size() - 1);
        ys.remove(ys.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

which *mostly* works. The logic is, whenever it gets two `Object[]`s, it checks to see if if it's currently comparing each of them higher up in the stack and, if so, it checks to see if the topmost stack-frame that's comparing one of them is also the topmost stack-frame that's comparing the other. (That *is* the logic you intended, right?)

The only serious bug I can see is in this sort of situation:

```
// a one-element array that directly contains itself:
final Object[] a = { null }; a[0] = a;
// a one-element array that contains itself via another one-element array:
final Object[][] b = { { null } }; b[0][0] = b;

// should return true (right?); instead, overflows the stack:
equal(a, b, new ArrayList<Object>(), new ArrayList<Object>());
```

You see, in the above, the last element of `xs` will always be `a`, but the last element of `ys` will alternate between `b` and `b[0]`. In each recursive call, `xs.lastIndexOf(a)` will always be the greatest index of `xs`, while `ys.lastIndexOf(b)` or `ys.lastIndexOf(b[0])` (whichever one is needed) will always be one *less* than the greatest index of `ys`.

The problem is, the logic shouldn't be, "the topmost comparison of `o1[i]` is in the same stack-frame as the topmost comparison of `o2[i]`"; rather, it should be, "there exists *some* stack-frame — any stack-frame at all — that is comparing `o1[i]` to `o2[i]`". But for efficiency, we can actually use the logic "there is, or has ever been, a stack-frame that is/was comparing `o1[i]` to `o2[i]`"; and we can use a `Set` of pairs of arrays rather than two `List`s of arrays. To that end, I wrote this:

```
private static boolean equal(final Object[] a1, final Object[] a2)
{
    return _equal(a1, a2, new HashSet<ArrayPair>());
}

private static boolean _equal
    (final Object[] a1, final Object[] a2, final Set<ArrayPair> pairs)
{
    if(a1 == a2)
        return true;
    if(a1.length != a2.length)
        return false;

    if(! pairs.add(new ArrayPair(a1, a2)))
    {
        // If we're here, then pairs already contained {a1,a2}. This means
        // either that we've previously compared a1 and a2 and found them to
        // be equal (in which case we obviously want to return true), or
        // that we're currently comparing them somewhere higher in the
        // stack and haven't *yet* found them to be unequal (in which case
        // we still want to return true: if it turns out that they're
        // unequal because of some later difference we haven't reached yet,
        // that's fine, because the comparison higher in the stack will
        // still find that).

        return true;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < a1.length; ++i)
    {
        if(a1[i] == a2[i])
            continue;
        if(a1[i] == null || a2[i] == null)
            return false;
        if(a1[i].equals(a2[i]))
            continue;
        if(! (a1[i] instanceof Object[]) || ! (a2[i] instanceof Object[]))
            return false;
        if(! _equal((Object[]) a1[i], (Object[]) a2[i], pairs))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private static final class ArrayPair
{
    private final Object[] a1;
    private final Object[] a2;

    public ArrayPair(final Object[] a1, final Object[] a2)
    {
        if(a1 == null || a2 == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();

        this.a1 = a1;
        this.a2 = a2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object that)
    {
        if(that instanceof ArrayPair)
            if(a1 == ((ArrayPair)that).a1)
                return a2 == ((ArrayPair)that).a2;
            else 
                if(a1 == ((ArrayPair)that).a2)
                    return a2 == ((ArrayPair)that).a1;
                else
                    return false;
        else
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
        { return a1.hashCode() + a2.hashCode(); }
}
```

It should be clear that the above cannot result in infinite recursion, because if the program has a finite number of arrays, then it has a finite number of pairs of arrays, and only one stack-frame at a time can be comparing a given pair of arrays (since, once a pair begins to be getting compared, it's added to `pairs`, and any future attempt to compare that pair will immediately return `true`), which means that the total stack depth is finite at any given time. (Of course, if the number of arrays is huge, then the above can still overflow the stack; the recursion is bounded, but so is the maximum stack size. I'd recommend, actually, that the `for`-loop be split into two `for`-loops, one after the other: the first time, skip all the elements that are arrays, and the second time, skip all the elements that aren't. This can avoid expensive comparisons in many cases.)

It should also be clear that the above will never return `false` when it should return `true`, since it only returns `false` when it finds an actual difference.

Lastly, I *think* it should be clear that the above will never return `true` when it should return `false`, since for every pair of objects, one full loop is always made over all the elements. This part is trickier to prove, but in essence, we've defined structural equality in such a way that two arrays are only structurally unequal if we can find some difference between them; and the above code does *eventually* examine every element of every array it encounters, so if there were a findable difference, it would find it.

Notes:

- I didn't worry about arrays of primitives, `int[]` and `double[]` and so on. Adam's answer raises the possibility that you would want these to be compared elementwise as well; if that's needed, it's easily added (since it wouldn't require recursion: arrays of primitives can't contain arrays), but the above code just uses `Object.equals(Object)` for them, which means reference-equality.
- The above code assumes that `Object.equals(Object)` implements a symmetric relation, as its contract specifies. In reality, however, that contract is not always fulfilled; for example, `new java.util.Date(0L).equals(new java.sql.Timestamp(0L))` is `true`, while `new java.sql.Timestamp(0L).equals(new java.util.Date(0L))` is `false`. If order matters for your purposes — if you want `equal(new Object[]{java.util.Date(0L)}, new Object[]{java.sql.Timestamp(0L)})` to be `true` and `equal(new Object[]{java.sql.Timestamp(0L)}, new Object[]{java.util.Date(0L)})` to be `false` — then you'll want to change `ArrayPair.equals(Object)`, and probably `ArrayPair.hashCode()` as well, to care about which array is which.

Comment: Interesting corner case you pointed out. I'm not sure to call them equal. If a pair of recursive calls were encountered, and they are on a different stack level (xs, ys) I would consider them as inequal. But if the entire structure is just a direct or indirect recursion, it unrolls to basically nothing. It seems the definition of what we consider equal is also under debate.

Comment: @kd304: The only reason that "the entire structure is just a direct or indirect recursion" is that I gave the minimal example that demonstrated this situation. You'd get the same result if `a` were `[0, a]` and `b` were `[0, [0, b]]`. I think these are definitely structurally equal, since both are `[0, [0, [0, [0, ...]]]]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could add all visited objects to a temporary `Map<Object, Object>` structure to make sure, that you do not visit/inspect them again. The value is always a new Object, which will be used to replace already visited instances in your result lists.

Every time you see an object,

1. Check, if the map contains the instance
2. if not, put it to the map, the map value is a new Object
3. if yes, use the map value (the unique, new Object) in your list (`xs` or `ys`)

In your example, the result lists should look like this (pseudo language):

```
xs == {o1, "A", obj2}     // obj2 == map.get(o2);
ys == {o2, "A", obj1}     // obj1 == map.get(o1);
```

This will prevent from infinite loops.

Comment: Yes, it is the same as my idea, except obj2 is a numeric index of when the object was last seen in the recursive descent.

Comment: Ah. OK!? - Your code is ... quite difficult to ... could have been a bit more self-explanatory.

Comment: @kd304: Your code and the suggestion of Andeas_D are really hard to match. Several points which are better in Andreas' suggestion: Using a linear search in two Lists will be slower than Using a IdentityHashMap. Also _one_ map is better than _two_ lists. Also the semantik of comparing the index values is not clear.

Comment: @A.H. IHM of course would make things faster, but the problem was about correctness. I have some doubts about the index comparison too, without it, the thing boils down to IdentityHashSet. The idea is that if both elements are found to be seen, and their recursion index mismatches, that might mean they are inequal. Unfortunately, my imagination is not good enough to think a case where this assumption is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this helper function to flatten each of the arrays and replaced its own reference with a string (or any primitive) for each level. The map will use a key-value store to keep track of the existing array objects (new at initialization). Assuming you have only arrays and comparable objects in the original array, you can compare the two flattened lists (with the same start level) without having to worry about infinite loops. This comparison should be linear.

```
private List<Object> flatten(Object[] array, Map<Object, String> map, int level) {
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object o : array) {
        if (o instanceof Object[]) {
            if (map.get(o) != null) {
                list.add(map.get(o));
            } else {
                map.put(array, "level"+level);
                List<Object> flattened = flatten((Object[]) o, map, level+1);
                for (Object obj : flattened)
                    list.add(obj);
            }
        } else {
            list.add(o);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've managed it, at least works in all test cases I've tried so far. Please can someone confirm if my logic is OK. Needed to use the lesser-know IdentityHashMap to keep track of previously visited nodes by reference.

Not sure how to deal with nested arrays of other primitives like int[] etc. I added case for int[], but there are float, double, byte, short, long, boolean to add.

```
public static boolean deepEquals(Object [] o1, Object [] o2) {
    return deepEquals(o1, o2, new IdentityHashMap<Object, Integer>());
}

public static boolean deepEquals(Object o1, Object o2, IdentityHashMap<Object, Integer> visited) {
    if (! visited.containsKey(o1)) {
        visited.put(o1, 0);
    } else {
        visited.put(o1, visited.get(o1) + 1);
    }
    if (! visited.containsKey(o2)) {
        visited.put(o2, 0);
    } else {
        visited.put(o2, visited.get(o2) + 1);
    }
    boolean ret = false;
    if (o1 == o2) {
        ret = true; 
    } else if (o1 instanceof Object[] && o2 instanceof Object[]){
        Object [] a1 = (Object[]) o1;
        Object [] a2 = (Object[]) o2;
        if (a1.length != a2.length ) {
            ret = false; // different length, can't be equal
        } else if (visited.get(o1) > 0 || visited.get(o2) > 0) {
            ret = true; // been here before, stop searching
        } else {
            ret = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
                if (! deepEquals(a1[i], a2[i], visited)) {
                    ret = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (o1 instanceof int[] && o2 instanceof int[]){
        ret = Arrays.equals((int[])o1, (int[])o2);
    } else if (o1 == null && o2 == null){
        ret = true; // null = null?
    } else {
        ret = o1.equals(o2); // just use equals
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: **A minor point:** since you're only consulting `visited` for arrays, not other objects, you don't actually need to use an `IdentityHashMap`, because you really only need to keep track of the *arrays* you've already seen, not other objects; and arrays' hash-codes indicate reference-identity anyway. So a regular `HashMap` will do. **A bigger point:** just because `o1` or `o2` has been visited, that doesn't mean that they've been compared to each other. If `a` is `[0]` and `b` is `[1]`, your logic returns `true` for `([a,a],[a,b])` just because `a` was visited at index-0 before you *[continued]*

Comment: *[continued]* got to index-1. Even if you change the `||` to `&&` to require that they *both* have been visited (which I think must have been your intent), your logic will still return `true` for `([a,b,a],[a,b,b])`.